# Garbage values when assigning values to two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, assembly, att, x86

I'm completely new to assembly and I've encountered an issue when assigning values to my two dimensional "array". My array is a `.space` named `screen` and is allocated with `HEIGHT * WIDTH * 4`, so there is enough space.

Before I do the commands below the array contains only `0` values (I know this because before issuing the commands below I loop through the array and set all values to `0`, and verified it by printing out all values).

This is what I do:

```
movl $0, %eax
movl $1, %ebx
movl $20, screen(%eax, %ebx, 4)
```

And this is what it results in (when listing all rows and columns):

```
x:0 y:0 value:0
x:0 y:1 value:20
x:0 y:2 value:0
x:0 y:3 value:0
x:0 y:4 value:0
x:1 y:0 value:335544320
x:1 y:1 value:0
x:1 y:2 value:0
x:1 y:3 value:0
x:1 y:4 value:0
x:2 y:0 value:1310720
x:2 y:1 value:0
x:2 y:2 value:0
x:2 y:3 value:0
x:2 y:4 value:0
x:3 y:0 value:5120
x:3 y:1 value:0
x:3 y:2 value:0
x:3 y:3 value:0
x:3 y:4 value:0
x:4 y:0 value:20
x:4 y:1 value:0
x:4 y:2 value:0
x:4 y:3 value:0
x:4 y:4 value:0
```

What I was expecting was only to see a change in `screen[0][1]`: `x:0 y:1 value:20`. What is causing these "garbage" values (`335544320`, `1310720`, `5120` etc)?

As I mentioned I'm a complete beginner, so be nice!

**Edit:**
I'm supplying the zero filling function and the function for listing all the values in the array.

```
HEIGHT = 5
WIDTH = 5
EMPTY = 0

.section .data
counter: .int 0
counter2: .int 0

str3: .string "x:%d y:%d value:%d\n"

.section .text
#################################
# Fill screen array with zeroes
init_screen:
#################################
movl    $0, counter
init_screen_array_x:

    movl    $0, counter2
init_screen_array_y:
    movl    counter, %ebx
    movl    counter2, %ecx
    movl    $EMPTY, screen(%ebx, %ecx, 4)

    incl    counter2
    cmpl    $HEIGHT, counter2
    jl  init_screen_array_y

    incl    counter
    cmpl    $WIDTH, counter
    jl  init_screen_array_x

    ret
#################################
# end init_screen
#################################

#################################
# Debugging function, list all values in array
list_screen_array:
#################################
movl    $0, counter
list_screen_array_x:

    movl    $0, counter2
list_screen_array_y:
    movl    counter, %ebx
    movl    counter2, %ecx

    pushl   screen(%ebx, %ecx, 4)
    pushl   counter2
    pushl   counter
    pushl   $str3
    call    printf
    addl    $16, %esp

    incl    counter2
    cmpl    $HEIGHT, counter2
    jl  list_screen_array_y

    incl    counter
    cmpl    $WIDTH, counter
    jl  list_screen_array_x

    ret
#################################
# end list_screen
#################################
```

**Edit 2**:
After the input from Andreas, I made this function:

```
# x should be stored in %eax
# y should be stored in %ebx
# saves address to screen[%eax][%ebx] in %eax
screen_get_address:
    imull $4, %eax
    imull $4, %ebx
    imull $WIDTH, %ebx
    addl %ebx, %eax
    addl screen, %eax
    ret
```

**Edit 3**
There's still something that isn't right. Now when doing this:

```
movl $0, %eax
movl $2, %ebx
call screen_get_address
movl $20, (%eax)
```

I get (3x3 array):

```
x:0 y:0 value:0
x:0 y:1 value:0
x:0 y:2 value:20
x:1 y:0 value:0
x:1 y:1 value:20
x:1 y:2 value:0
x:2 y:0 value:20
x:2 y:1 value:0
x:2 y:2 value:0
```

Comment: I would say the program works as expected. You have a 20 in the position you wrote it to. You can not expect that the remaining memory is filled with zeros after you start a program. In fact it is uninitialized, i.e. if you want it to contain zeros, fill it with zeros explicitly!

Comment: I understand that too, but as I stated, the array contain ONLY zero values before I do the `movl $20, screen(%eax, %ebx, 4)`. I know this since I looped through the array and explicitly set all values to zero. So somehow the `movl` changes values in other places as well!?

Comment: Hmm, I am very sure that the movl command writes 4 bytes to address "screen+4" so it changes bytes screen+4 to screen+7. I suspect that the error is either in the "zero filling" or in the way you generate the output you show in the post.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I edited my post with my zero filling and listing function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to compute the address is wrong.
To access the (%ebx=x,%ecx=y) element of a 2D dword array you need to access the data at

```
 screen + 4*(%ecx*WIDTH + %ebx)
```

you are accessing screen(%ebx, %ecx, 4), which is

```
screen + %ebx + 4*%ecx
```

i.e. the wrong position. Prior to your movl instruction you have to generate the address first (e.g using MUL, or, if WIDTH is a power of 2, using the shift instruction). If you only want to loop over all elements, you can spare the complicated address calculation by using just a single pointer which is continuously incremented.

Comment: Thank you! Could you have a look at the function I did and see if it is correct or not? I updated my post!

Comment: Seems ok to me. Note that you can spare the both imul $4, %ebx/%%ecx by just replacing the line addl screen, %eax by leal screen(,%eax,4),%eax (which  is eax = 4*eax + screen). Also addresses are unsigned (mul instead of imul), although this typically will make no difference.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I updated my post again. It doesn't seem to work correctly after all :(

Comment: I dont see any error, you probably have to run a debugger if you can not find the mistake.